# Is there a way to find the list of files added freshly/newly to a cvs repository

Tags: cvs

is there a way to find the list of files added freshly/newly to a cvs repository

FYI : CVS history command doesn't work on my system due to corruption

Comment: How do you know it is corrupted? Can you see $CVSROOT Are the permissions on $CVSROOT okay?

Answer (score 2):

If your repository is corrupted such that `cvs history` does not work, I doubt you'll be able to find a command that will reliably work.

Answer (score 0):

What about "CVS History" command ?

Comment: CVS history command doesn't work on my system due to corruption

Answer (score 0):

you could set up commitlogs...
If you have access to $CVSROOT you can modify loginfo to have it write to a file when a commit has occurred

$CVSROOT/loginfo:

```
#DEFAULT (echo ""; id; echo %s; date; cat) >> $CVSROOT/CVSROOT/commitlog 
# or 
#DEFAULT (echo ""; id; echo %{sVv}; date; cat) >> $CVSROOT/CVSROOT/commitlog
```

This writes the log messages of *ALL* modules in the repository to the 
file 'commitlog'

Answer (score 0):

you could set up watches and get emailed when a file in the repository is modified...
If you have access to $CVSROOT you can modify notify to have it send email when a file is checked in

$CVSROOT/notify:

```
ALL /bin/mail -s "CVS notification" %s
```

or

```
ALL mail %s -s \"CVS notification\"
```

do cvs watch on
checkout each module and do a
cvs watch add -a commit

be sure to check on the manual http://developer.apple.com/opensource/cvs/cederquist/cvs_84.html